# Matlab/Octave - Function of multiple lines - plot

Tags: matlab, variables, plot, octave

Im trying to run a octave/matlab script where I would like to plot a simple function - But the function consist of multiple lines, and therfore I cant get it to plot correctly.

My code is:

```
x = linspace(0,200000);
c=sqrt((x/mmPrRev).^2+Akselafstand^2-2*(x/mmPrRev)*Akselafstand*acos(1));
Vinkelaendring = acosd((Akselafstand^2+c.^2-(x/mmPrRev).^2)/(2*Akselafstand*c));
offset=(sind(Vinkelaendring)*1000000)/(sind(90-Vinkelaendring));

plot (x,offset);
xlabel ("x");
ylabel ("y");
title ("Simple 2-D Plot");
```

When I plot "offset" it is just a line, but I can plot "c" without a problem - It seems like it cant change the X value when i use offset - What do i need to change? Thanks!

Comment: The _real_ problem with the code above is that you have undefined variables. Depending on how these are defined the ways in which the above snippet can fail to give the correct results can change. However, on the assumption that you meant all the undefined variables to be scalars, then presumably you meant to do `./` instead of `/` in the Vinkelaendring step

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - The missing variables is defined longer up in my project - All variables are defined and calculated there, the only one missing is the "x" variable. -

Comment: Hi Martin. Welcome to SO. To clarify, I didn't mean that it wasn't clear to me that this is not a standalone script. I meant that not giving a standalone script is unhelpful since one cannot help if they don't know if the problem lies elsewhere. Always strive to provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that could be run directly in the console by people trying to help with your problem. Not least because more often than not, the process of trying to reduce the problem to its bare bones often helps you [solve it yourself](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) first.

Comment: as Tasos already wrote: Try to reduce your script to a minimum which can be run without having external dependencies such as data files or other function files. In most cases, you'll find your error yourself. But if not others can copy&paste your snippet and start helping from there